# Как побороть утечку памяти в Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, память, утечка-памяти

Есть достаточно большой проект на Python, запускается несколько процессов, процессы запускают потоки (это если коротко). Так вот при работе это все хозяйство течет по памяти, сейчас костыль: перезапускается раз в несколько часов. Хотелось бы выяснить, какими средствами можно выяснить причину утечки памяти?

Comment: Профайлер юзайте

Comment: Есть прекрасная утилита, облегчающая поиск утечек - [Python Object Graphs](https://mg.pov.lt/objgraph/).